# MVAPICH 2.3 configure for multiple devices

Tags: tcp, infiniband, mvapich2

While mvapich from version 2.3 deprecated the Nemesis interface, is there any way now to configure it at once for Infiniband support with fallback to TCP when failed? Or do I have to have two compilations for different network setups in my grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my question with the information from MVAPICH developers:

> At this point, the default MVAPICH channel cannot use TCP as a fallback if IB fails. We will see if such a support can be enabled in the future.